# Can't make and receive calls with good signal

Tags: connection-issues

Sometimes my smartphone can't make or receive calls (haven't tried SMS) despite signal being good. I can connect to LTE internet though. Turning airplane mode on and off solves the problem however it's not a proper solution because that problem can happen again and I won't know it.

Anyone can advise?
Thanks.

Samsung Galaxy A71

Android 10, One UI 2.1

Comment: Does your carrier (and your device) support Voice over LTE (VoLTE). Without that for a voice call the device has to drop LTE connection and fall back to 3G or 2G depending what is available. Of course this means that the signal strength can change if the cell towers are different to the before used LTE tower.

Comment: My carrier supports VOLTE and I also see VOLTE symbol next to cellular signal strength bars.